# Difference between match parameter and RequestContext in Symfony Router UrlMatcher

Tags: php, symfony

I don't understand the semantics of the Symfony Routing Component's API.

From the first code example on [the Routing Component documentation page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing.html):

```
$context = new RequestContext('/');

$matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $context);

$parameters = $matcher->match('/foo');
```

Why is the hostname and HTTP method passed in via `$context` and the path via a parameter to `match()`? Or is it? There is also a `path` parameter in the `RequestContext` constructor.

One gets the impression `match()` is supposed to be called multiple times with different paths within one request, which I can't imagine would ever happen.

Comment: Just speculating but since the first param of `RequestContext` is the `baseUrl`, I presume it allows matching in different contexts; e.g: if the request context is `/bar/` it's possible to match on `/foo` if the actual URI is `/bar/foo`?

Comment: Of course, if that's the case, you could just match on `/bar/foo` but perhaps this flexibility is required/desirable for some purpose—for instance if using route annotations, you can define a prefix at controller level and define additional short form routes on each method.

Comment: Still it makes no sense to pass half the information to the constructor and half to `match()`. One gets the impression `match()` is supposed to be called multiple times with different paths within one request, which I can't imagine would ever happen.

Comment: Oh and while in the example `baseUrl` is set, there is actually a third path (called `path`) that *can* be set in the RequestContext. I edited the question to compare with that one, because your argument about the `baseUrl` being a convenience feature makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

After integrating the Routing Component into my application, I now have a hunch why 
it was done like that.

Most of the properties of the RequestContext - method, request body, get parameters - can be used without modification, but depending on the desired path structure and server configuration (rewrite rules, etc.) there are multiple ways in which the path needs to be preprocessed.

This doesn't explain why the path is passed to the `match()` function and the request object is passed to the constructor, but it does explain why they are passed in separately.